# Click on elements with dyanmic url change in xpath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The below css Selector I have written.

.custom-scrollbar .content-row:nth-of-type(1) [src='https://static-qa.xxxxxxxxx.com/csp/images/rotate_action_icon.svg']

[image]

Problem is i need to click on that edit button but issue is url changes with respect to env. Example- currently its pointing to qa so the url is qa, if its in prod then it will change due to which web element not found error occurs.

I am trying with below code which doesnot works-

```
List<WebElement> list = pilot.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
        String aa = list.get(3).getAttribute("src");
        list.get(2).click();
```

Please suggest a better approach to play around with these buttons with dynamic url.

Comment: I'm not sure if any one will write the html code from the image for you. Share it as part of post as code not as image. It wont help to reproduce the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following css selector to `startswith` and  `endswith`

```
img[src^='https://static-'][src$='com/csp/images/rotate_action_icon.svg']
```